# Firebase notifications conversions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am just starting using Firebase in my Android App. I can receive perfectly a notification from Firebase console on my device, that's amazing.

My question to you is, in the firebase console when you see the messages sent in Notifications, when I open a sample notification, I can not see the people who i sent the notifiacion, opened the notifaction, the conversions that i have.

Am I missing something? Should I implement anything to response to server with device-id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Notification events stats are found in the Analytics tab. Firebase automatically logs some events for you - see list [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events).

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything, it's just that the information about sent, open and conversions events **it's not in realtime** . Indeed it will take few hours for that information to be computed and presented in the console.

Comment: Hi @DiegoGiorigini sir. I was wondering, how the `Opened` and `Conversion` is identified. Is there an automatic function in FCM that identifies if the Notification sent in the client is clicked/opened?